# PCIe Plugin - Can't Make Serial Port Work

Tags: serial-port, pci-e

I have a simple card plugged into the PCIe slot on my motherboard.  The card has a serial and parallel port.  I would like to be able to read and write to/from the serial port.  I have tried several approaches found online, both in C and Python, but without success.  All attempts to use mmap have failed.

I expect to be able to read and write to/from the serial port with simple commands.

````
Linux 5.15.0-76-generic #83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 21 20:23:31 UTC 2023 GNU/Linux```

```04:00.0 Serial controller: Device 1c00:3250 (rev 10) (prog-if 05 [16850])
    Subsystem: Device 1c00:3250
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 21
    Region 0: I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Region 1: Memory at 91108000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at c100 [size=4]
    Expansion ROM at 91100000 [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <2us, L1 <32us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
             10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Kernel driver in use: parport_serial
    Kernel modules: parport_serial```

This is code that I've tried, modeled after code found online:

```#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void){
    char * path = "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/resource0";
    int fd, err;
    struct stat statbuf;
    char * ptr;
    ssize_t n;

    fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0){
        printf("Could not open %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    err = fstat(fd, &statbuf);
    if (err < 0){
        printf("fstat error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
//Error occurs here: No such device
    ptr = mmap(NULL, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("Map failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    n = write(1, ptr, statbuf.st_size);
    if (n != statbuf.st_size){
        printf("Write failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}```
````